# Syntax issue within if statement

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble figuring out this error. The console tells me that the semi-colon on the line that I've bolded below is causing an 'unexpected token' error. I can't figure out why. The line is :

**wrapper.classList.remove("hidepricing100");**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

        var itemlist = document.getElementsByClassName("costbasedonotherservice");

        var basepricearray = [];

        for (var i=0; i < itemlist.length; i++) {
            var baseprice = itemlist[i].innerText;
            basepricearray.push(baseprice);
        }

        var multiplier = $('#costsbasedonthisservice select :selected').attr('value');

        $('#costsbasedonthisservice select').on('change', function() {

            var multiplier = $('#costsbasedonthisservice select :selected').attr('value');

            for (var i=0; i < itemlist.length; i++) {

                var newprice = basepricearray[i]*multiplier;
                var newprice2 = Number(newprice).toFixed(2); 
                var wrapper = itemlist[i].parentElement;

                if (newprice2 == 0){
                    wrapper.classList.add("hidepricing100");
                } else (
                    **wrapper.classList.remove("hidepricing100");**                 
                    itemlist[i].innerText = newprice2;
                )
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `} else (` change to `{` and `}`

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I missed that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You placed ( and ) after your else statement rather than { and }:

Code after Correction:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        var itemlist = document.getElementsByClassName("costbasedonotherservice");
        var basepricearray = [];
        for (var i=0; i < itemlist.length; i++) {
            var baseprice = itemlist[i].innerText;
            basepricearray.push(baseprice);
        }
        var multiplier = $('#costsbasedonthisservice select :selected').attr('value');
        $('#costsbasedonthisservice select').on('change', function() {
            var multiplier = $('#costsbasedonthisservice select :selected').attr('value');
            for (var i=0; i < itemlist.length; i++) {
                var newprice = basepricearray[i]*multiplier;
                var newprice2 = Number(newprice).toFixed(2); 
                var wrapper = itemlist[i].parentElement;
                if (newprice2 == 0){
                    wrapper.classList.add("hidepricing100");
                } else {
                    **wrapper.classList.remove("hidepricing100");**                 
                    itemlist[i].innerText = newprice2;
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The else condition is still ending with a ) in your code, but I know what you mean. If you make the correction, I'll accept this as the answer.

Comment: Thanks, Jason! and yes, I got your point too

Comment: Questions caused by typos should be flagged and closed, not answered.

Comment: Hey @CertainPerformance , Thanks :) will keep this in mind